# Displaying output before headers are set in PHP

Tags: php, http-headers

I have an HTML form that submits its data via POST to a server page:

```
<form id='report-inputs' method='post' action='generate.php'>...</form>
```

`generate.php` is does a lot of work with the data its given, to finally dump out an Excel file for download. It does this by cleaning the buffer and setting the headers:

```
ob_end_clean();
header('Set-Cookie: fileDownloadToken='.$token); 
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$_DATA['title'].'.xlsx"');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Without `ob_end_clean()` the file downloads as corrupt. I would like to display some sort of confirmation or something when the page finishes its processing, but the caveat there is that any page output is cleared before render with `ob_end_clean()`.

What can I do to display some content AND deliver the file successfully?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't make the response do two things at the same time. Either it's text/html or it's application/vnd.ms-excel. You'll have to split it up into separate parts.

Comment: Understood. The confirmation page I intended on showing was going to be relative to the data that was submitted in the first place. For example, if I submitted "Project X, Product Y", once the output was processed, I want the page to say "Thank you for your interest in Project X, Product Y". I know I can insert `<script>window.location('somewhere.php')</script>` but I need the data to follow it.

Comment: @MikeB Actually, I can't insert a `<script>` block. The headers would have already been changed...

Answer (score 1):

Save the data into a file, display whatever you wish on the screen, and add a Javascript redirect to the file you saved.

Answer (score 1):

As @mike-b already stated, you can't make the same response do two things at once.  But here's what you **can** do.

1. Your PHP script should create the download file and save it as a temporary file on the server.
2. Return a page to the user saying, "Thank you for your interest in Project X..." or whatever.
3. The output page should, after a decent interval, redirect the user to the download file's URL.  Or you could provide an actual link for them to click on.  Or both.

Comment: I have considered that, but I am against it because I do not want to give the user the impression that their file is downloadable whenever they use the link. Instead I'm going to submit the form twice. The first time will remain exactly as it does now. When the file is received in the browser, I'm going to submit it a second time but with an additional piece of data that says not to build the file, but rather return some HTML that is contains the context of the choices the user has made. I will then use javascript to replace the page contents with the html returned from the second submit.